# Geometry: Proving length of radius

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

In the image above, given in circle with center *O*, *BC* = 20 and *AD* = 15, and *PQ* is parallel to *BC*, which contains the tangent point *F*, how can I find the length of the radius?

Answer (score 0):

You use the fact that $APQ$ and $ABC$ are similar and that $PO$, $OQ$, $OF$ and $GD$ are all equal.

You get that $PQ$ is to $BC$ as $AG$ is to $AD$. Also you have that since $PO$, $OQ$, $GD$ and $OF$ are all the same so $PQ$ is twice $GD$. Then you combine this into the equation:

$$2r = b ( 1 - r/h)$$

Where $b$ is the base, $r$ the radius and $h$ the height. Then you solve that for $r$

$$r = {bh \over 2h+b}$$

And insert $b=20$ and $h=15$ and get $r=6$

Comment: How did you know that _PQ_ is to _BC_ as _AG_ is to _GD_?

Comment: And where is this formula from? _2r=b(1−r/h)_?

Comment: @danilejt A bit wrong that section which I updated. The equation then follows from this, $1-r/h = (h-r)/r$ is the ratio of the heights of the triangles, and $2r/b$ is the ratio of their bases.

Comment: Thank you for updating. I still don't understand where the formula is from?

Comment: i.e. I understand that _PQ_ is twice the radius. I also understand (PQ)(AD)=(BC)(AG). But that would get me (2r)(15) = (20)(AG) and I don't know how you knew what AG was?

Comment: How could you call it "1"?

Comment: danilejt, note $AG=AD-GD=15-r$

Answer (score 0):

The area of $\Delta ABC$ is equal to the sum of areas of $\Delta APQ$ and trapezoid $BCQP$:
$$A_{\Delta ABC}=\frac12\cdot BC\cdot AD=\frac12\cdot 20\cdot 15;\\
A_{\Delta APQ}=\frac12\cdot PQ\cdot AG=\frac12\cdot 2r\cdot (AD-GD)=\frac12\cdot 2r\cdot (15-r);\\
A_{BCQP}=\frac{BC+PQ}{2}\cdot GD=\frac{20+2r}{2}\cdot r;\\
\frac12\cdot 20\cdot 15=\frac12\cdot 2r\cdot (15-r)+\frac12\cdot (20+2r)\cdot r\Rightarrow \\
300=50r \Rightarrow \\
r=6.$$